# PostgreSQL join duplicates rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and I am new to it. I am attempting to join a table to two other tables but the results are being duplicated. I have the following tables.

MEAL

| id | name | ingredients | flavors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | Creamy Chicken Soup | {def,ghi,jkl} | {mno} |

INGREDIENT

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| def | chicken |
| ghi | corn |
| jkl | pepper |

FLAVOR

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| mno | spicy |

And here is my query

```
SELECT
   meal.id,
   meal.name,
   JSON_AGG(i) as ing,
   JSON_AGG(f) as flav,
FROM meal LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT
      ingredient.id,
      ingredient.name
   FROM ingredient) i
      ON (i.id = ANY(meal.ingredients)) LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT
      flavor.id,
      flavor.name
   FROM flavor) f
      ON (f.id = ANY(meal.flavors))
GROUP BY
   meal.id,
   meal.name
```

And the results are:

| id | name | ing | flav |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | Creamy Chicken Soup | [{id: "def",name:"chicken"},{id:"ghi",name:"corn"},{id:"jkl",name:"pepper"}] | [{id:"mno",name:"spicy"},{id:"mno",name:"spicy"},{id:"mno",name:"spicy"}] |

As you can see the flavors are being duplicated the same number of times as the ingredient count. How can I do this query without the duplicates. Unfortunatly I do not have any control over the table structure as it is being pulled in from a third party. I can maniputlate the data in code but I would prefer to query it and get back the correct data set.

Comment: Try adding a flavor id as an extra grouping field: `GROUP BY meal.id, meal.name, f.id`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but unfortunately it did not fix the duplicate issue.